# How to validate Angular material form field for Year

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a form field called Purchase Year. This field is editable, but I need to allow users to enter only valid years(i.e., 2020). if user enters any invalid number or text, I should show validation error message.

I have seen many recommendations on Google to have datepicker but in my case I need year value alone. Can somebody help me to write this code?

```
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-label>Purchase Year<mat-icon class="required">star_rate</mat-icon></mat-label>
     <input matInput formControlName="PurchaseYear" placeholder="Purchase Year">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: What's wrong with this question? Why did you close it?

Answer (score 1):

can you validate it as nubmer?

```
userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     PurchaseYear: [2020
      , Validators.min(2020)],
      , Validators.max(2020)]
});
```